# How do I get pool information from org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory?

Tags: spring, spring-data-redis

I'm using spring-data-redis to connect redis server.
I want to get jedis' connection pool information via RedisConnectionFactory or RedisConnectionFactory.
But I can't found the way to get pool object from RedisConnectionFactory.

(I guess, if there's JedisConectionFactory#getPool(), i can take the connection pool object itself)

Answer (score 1):

The `pool` field in `JedisConnectionFactory` is private and is not exposed by a getter. Your only option is to obtain the field using reflection. Besides the pool itself, you can obtain `JedisPoolConfig` by calling `JedisConnectionFactory.getPoolConfig()`.

Please also note that pooling is optional (enabled by default) and can be disabled by setting `JedisConnectionFactory.setUsePool(false)`.