# How to get the current info of the JedisPool

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis

When I use spring-data-redis inject RedisConnectionFactory and setup the poolConfig, how can I get the infomation of the pool in runtime, because I found the factory does not expose the pool. Thank you advance.^.^

my code is :

```
@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {

    JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    poolConfig.setMaxIdle(128);
    poolConfig.setJmxEnabled(true);
    poolConfig.setMaxTotal(8);
    poolConfig.setMinIdle(2);

    JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory(poolConfig);
    factory.setHostName("localhost");
    factory.setPort(6379);
    factory.setUsePool(true);

    return factory;
}
```

Comment: That's possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450852/how-do-i-get-pool-information-from-org-springframework-data-redis-connection-jed

Comment: @mp911de, thank you for your post, maybe reflection is the only way to get the infomation of pool. :)